# Using preprocessor statements for Macros in C

Tags: c, function, debugging, macros

I am making a program that shifts values left or right depending on the value of the 2nd argument. If it is positive then it shifts left, else it shifts right. N is the number of times it shifts left or right. I am having trouble in implementation of my Macros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHIFT(value, n) 

#if (n) > 0
    (unsigned int value) <<= (int n);
#else 
    ( (unsigned int value)) >>= (int -n);



int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", SHIFT(1, 4));
}
```

Currently I am getting a conditional directive error.

Comment: Try ` #define SHIFT(value, n) \ `. A backslash at the end indicates next line is part of current line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C preprocessor doesn't really work the way you intend to use it. In particular, you cannot use other CPP directives (like `#if`, ...) in the expansion of a macro. Besides, since macro expansion is a static compile-time feature, this wouldn't help anyway, when the actual shift-values are only known at run-time:

```
int value_to_shift = read_some_integer_from_user();
int amount_to_shift_by = read_another_integer_from_user();
int shifted_value = SHIFT(value_to_shift, amount_to_shift_by);
```

If you don't mind the potential double-evaluation of macro arguments, go with the ternary operator:

```
#define SHIFT(value, n)   ( (n) < 0? ((value) >> (-n)) : ((value) << (n)) )
```

Note, that using `<<=` (and `>>=`) as you do in the code is most likely not what you want, given, that you pass literal numbers as `value` arguments to your the `SHIFT` macro.

I would probably go for a tiny helper function here instead of a macro:

```
static int 
shift(int value, int nbits)
{
    return nbits < 0? (value >> -nbits) : (value << nbits);
}
```

Comment: Okay. Is there any way to do this with using data types in arguments?

Comment: @XiJiaopin: And why do you want that?

Comment: It would be appropriate in this specific program which is derived from shifting with unsigned integers

Comment: @XiJiaopin -- In C++, you could use a template. In C, there is currently no way I could think of. Depending on your compiler, you might be able to cook something up using the mechanism used to implement the (type generic math)[http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/tgmath] stuff of C99. I haven't used that myself at all, and cannot tell, whether this would be a viable way at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `#define` isn't doing what you think it does. You need to continue the lines with `\`. And since n is known at runtime (assuming your case is just a simplification) you can use a regular function, and inline it if needed:

```
inline int shift(int value, int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return (unsigned int) value << n;
    }
    else {
         return (unsigned int) value << -n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your cast syntax looks odd. Did you mean `(unsigned int)value`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the lines with a `\`. you also missed thed `#endif`

Inplace macro:

```
#define SHIFT(value, n)        \
     value = ((n) > 0)  ?      \
             value << (n) :    \
             value >> -(n)
```

Return shifted value:

```
#define SHIFT(value, n)        \
     ( ((n) > 0)  ?            \
             (value) << (n) :  \
             (value) >> -(n) )
```

Comment: I know that's why I wrote it wouldn't work. Better to remove it then.